# Bot is deleting messages too slow

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
let channelTarget = client.channels.cache.get(splitMsg[2].replaceAll(/[<#>]+/ig, ''));
    
    if (!allowedChannelsSend.includes(splitMsg[2].replaceAll(/[<#>]+/ig, ''))) {
      return msg.reply(`This command needs a valid channel. \`\`${commandsList[6].name}[number][channel]\`\`.`);
    }

    async function purging (counter) {
      let data = await channelTarget.messages.fetch({ limit: [100]})
      let messageArr = [...data];
      for (let i=0; i<messageArr.length; i++) {
        console.log(messageArr[i][1].id);
        await channelTarget.messages.delete(messageArr[i][1].id);
        counter-=1;
        if (counter > 0) {
          console.log(counter);
        } else {  
          return msg.reply(`Deleted **\`\` ${splitMsg[1]-counter} \`\`** messages in ${splitMsg[2]} channel.`); 
        };
      };
      //Check if user wanted to delete more than limit, Timeout makes sure it's the last bit of code to execute
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (messageArr[0] != null && counter > 0) {
          purging(counter);
        } else {  
          return msg.reply(`Deleted **\`\` ${splitMsg[1]-counter} \`\`** messages in ${splitMsg[2]} channel.`); 
        };
      }, 1);
    }
    purging(Number(splitMsg[1]));
```

This thing is made to continue deleting messages over the discord limit, the problem is - it's deleting 3-4 then stopping and then deleting some more and then stopping. What can I do?

Comment: Not sure but try: `await purging(Number(splitMsg[1]));`.

Comment: that's invalid syntax

Comment: Is this `if` statement not inside an `async` function?

Comment: ``if`` is inside a ``timeout`` inside the ``purge`` function

Comment: By `if` statement I meant the one in the first line of the code provided by you.

Comment: no that's just to detect a command

Comment: As you mentioned its stopping and deleting again, it's probably getting ratelimited..

Comment: how do I avoid that?

Comment: It does appear like it is being rate limited, and as far as I'm aware unless you'd get some kind of special permission given by Discord you are not able to go over it. The only way around it would be to have multiple bots synchronously performing the deletes **which by the way is not allowed**.

Comment: I mean can I limit the speed of my for loop that deletes messages?

Answer (score 0):

you are mostlikely getting rate limited.  Discord doesn't take kindly to API Spam calls (like a big loop for deleting messages).  you have a couple of options:

1. deal with the slowness (stinks...but hopefully you're not doing this often)
2. ask the channel owner to delete and re-create the channel, if there is a long history of messages to be deleted.
3. use bulkDelete(), which will purge all messages <14 days old in a single call.